Duplicate values after Copy Activity in Fabric pipeline
I am working on a Microsoft Fabric pipeline and I want to copy some data from an API URL to the Fabric Lakehouse and the problem I'm facing is that it writes to the table in the Lakehouse same data duplicated 864 times and I don't understand why.
I also have an Authentication header and the OSvC-CREST-Application-Context header which is required in order to retrieve data from this api.
I am doing this using the Copy Data Activity and for now I just want to get the details of one element using an API URL similar to this: https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/items/1
and the result of this api call looks something like this:
{
    "id": 1,
    "lookupName": "ITEM1",
    "createdTime": "2016-01-19T11:08:02.000Z",
    "updatedTime": "2024-11-06T08:57:50.000Z",
    "locations": {
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/items/1/locations"
            },
            {
                "rel": "full",
                "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/items/1/locations/{location_id}",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "banner": {
        "importanceFlag": {
            "id": 3,
            "lookupName": "High"
        },
        "text": " ",
        "updatedByperson": {
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/persons/2"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "canonical",
                    "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/persons/2"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "describedby",
                    "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/metadata-catalog/persons",
                    "mediaType": "application/schema+json"
                }
            ]
        },
        "updatedTime": "2016-01-22T15:00:26.000Z"
    },
    "customFields": {
        "c": {
            "maintenance": true,
            "blacklist": false,
            "org_remote": null,
            "tip_cont": {
                "id": 68,
                "lookupName": "abc"
            },
            "amef_cnt": null,
            "term_date": null,
            "term_reason": null,
            "phisical_country": "Romania"
        }
    },
    "externalReference": null,
    "attachments": {
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/items/1/attachments"
            },
            {
                "rel": "full",
                "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/items/1/attachments/{attachment_id}",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "industry": null,
    "login": "log.in",
    "name": "item1",
    "nameFurigana": null,
    "notes": {
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/items/1/notes"
            },
            {
                "rel": "full",
                "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/items/1/notes/{note_id}",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "itemHierarchy": {
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/items/1/itemHierarchy"
            },
            {
                "rel": "full",
                "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/items/1/itemHierarchy/{itemHierarchy_id}",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "parent": null,
    "actionSettings": {
        "acquiredDate": null,
        "actionperson": {
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/persons/2"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "canonical",
                    "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/persons/2"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "describedby",
                    "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/metadata-catalog/persons",
                    "mediaType": "application/schema+json"
                }
            ]
        },
        "total": {
            "currency": {
                "id": 2,
                "lookupName": "RON"
            },
            "exchangeRate": null
        }
    },
    "serviceSettings": {
        "sLAInstances": {
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/items/1/serviceSettings/sLAInstances"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "full",
                    "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/items/1/serviceSettings/sLAInstances/{sLAInstance_id}",
                    "templated": true
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "source": {
        "id": 10,
        "lookupName": "Contact",
        "parents": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "lookupName": "consola"
            }
        ]
    },
    "supersededBy": null,
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/items/1"
        },
        {
            "rel": "canonical",
            "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/items/1"
        },
        {
            "rel": "describedby",
            "href": "https://mysite.example.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/metadata-catalog/items",
            "mediaType": "application/schema+json"
        }
    ]
}

I don't think there is a need of pagination rules, but I have set initially as pagination rules RFC5988 = True and then I changed to MaxRequestNumber=1 just to test if I get other result, and no, the result was the same.
And the output of the pipeline after running looks like this:
{
    "dataRead": 16168,
    "dataWritten": 5933,
    "filesWritten": 1,
    "sourcePeakConnections": 1,
    "sinkPeakConnections": 1,
    "rowsRead": 1,
    "rowsCopied": 864,
    "copyDuration": 17,
    "throughput": 1.47,
    "errors": [],
    "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 4,
    "usedParallelCopies": 1,
    "executionDetails": [
        {
            "source": {
                "type": "RestService"
            },
            "sink": {
                "type": "Lakehouse"
            },
            "status": "Succeeded",
            "start": "12/13/2024, 4:35:22 PM",
            "duration": 17,
            "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 4,
            "usedParallelCopies": 1,
            "profile": {
                "queue": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 6
                },
                "transfer": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 11,
                    "details": {
                        "readingFromSource": {
                            "type": "RestService",
                            "workingDuration": 0,
                            "timeToFirstByte": 0
                        },
                        "writingToSink": {
                            "type": "Lakehouse",
                            "workingDuration": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "detailedDurations": {
                "queuingDuration": 6,
                "timeToFirstByte": 0,
                "transferDuration": 11
            }
        }
    ],
    "dataConsistencyVerification": {
        "VerificationResult": "Unsupported"
    }
}

Why do I get duplicated values and how can I solve it?
Or maybe there is an alternative way of getting the data from an api, like getting the data using Web Activity and then write it in the lakehouse with another activity?!

Can you provide your copy activity source and sink configurations? and is this same result in normal ADF pipeline?

I didn't tried it in normal ADF pipeline because I don't have a licence for it.
To connect to the API I used an HTTP Connection, put this url: https://mysite.example.com, and set the Authentication kind to Anonymous, added this /services/rest/connect/v1.4/items/1 in RelativeURL and added the authorization token as an additional header.
For the destination I just created a lakehouse in microsoft fabric and connected to it and then I have entered a table name in the Table field and it created it automatically in the lakehouse and for now I am overwritting it everytime the pipeline runs.

You can follow below procedure to achieve your requirement:
Create a pipeline and run web activity to retrieve the details of Api as below:

After successful execution of pipeline web activity will retrieve the details of Api, create linked service of Rest Api for source and lake house linked service for sink. Add foreach activity on success of web activity, add below range function as items for foreach activity:
@range(1,activity('restAPI').output.total_pages)
Inside the for each activity add copy activity, Create Rest Api dataset with dataset parameter  rurl  with value  @dataset().rurl  by using created linked service, add it as source of copy activity and set get activity as request method and add value  ?page=@{item()}  for  rurl  as shown below:

Create lake house dataset with dataset parameter  tablename  for table by using created linked service, add it to sink with value  Apipage@{item()} tablename  and enable auto create table. Mapp the data according to the requirements. Debug the pipeline and it will execute successfully. The data is copied successfully as shown below:

In sample Api there are two pages that's why created 2 tables with complete data.
